# Executing doctest Unitests from Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, nose, doctest

I am struggling to find a good, well documented approach for execution of doctest-based Python unit test from the Jenkins continuous integration server.

I have seen approaches where the doctests are [executed by nose](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/doctests.html).

Does anyone know of the approach for executing Pyhton doctests from Jenkins.
(Will try [this](http://www.alexconrad.org/2011/10/jenkins-and-python.html) approach)

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?